# why ng new project_name is not working in angular 11?

Tags: deprecated, tslint, angular11

Installing packages (npm)...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.3: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information. npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies. npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2. npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated npm ERR! cb() never called! npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at: npm ERR! https://npm.community npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\gupta\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-30T09_24_41_159Z-debug.log × Package install failed, see above. The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot to solve this error and finally i solved it,
i ignored this deprecated warning and then changed directory

> `cd project_name` then i fired `ng serve --hmr` command
> but didn't worked,
> so finally inside the project folder.
> `npm install` and again
> `ng serve --hmr`

These steps worked for me